# SQL Query inside a table

Tags: mysql, security, subquery, badge

I'm building a badge system very similar to the way StackExchange's badges work. In order to query the individual badge eligibility, it seems the optimal solution is to place an SQL query inside a table so that it can be executed as part of a cron job.

Here's the query style I'm thinking of using:

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM comments c
    WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id
) > 0
AND [$badge_id] NOT IN (
    SELECT b.badge_id
    FROM user_badges b
    WHERE b.user_id = u.user_id
)
```

The table would end up looking like this:

```
badge_id |    name         |  description  | level |     hash     | query
---------+-----------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | Hello World     | First comment |   1   | 50a7c570f... | u.user_id FROM users u WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id ) > 0
2        | Into the Breach | First thread  |   1   | 6b01e9348... | u.user_id FROM users u WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM threads t WHERE t.user_id = u.user_id ) > 0
```

The query is fetched from the database, prefixed with `SELECT` and then the `AND [$badge_id] NOT IN (...)` subquery condition is appended. It then replaces `[$badge_id]` with the current badge ID. The query is executed and returns a list of user IDs that should be given the badge.

The hash field is used to store a HMAC-SHA1 hash of the query, using a key defined in the PHP script. The idea behind this is that even if an SQL injection attack occured, the attacker wouldn't have access to the key in the script and would not be able to forge a more dangerous query.

I have two questions:

1. Is SQL in a table a really really bad method? If so, why? I'm open to alternatives.
2. Is there a more efficient query to achieve the same query? Subqueries are usually pretty slow in my experience.

I'd also be interested to know how the StackExchange code does it.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad idea.  What if you ever change your schema?  Now you have to go and invalidate every single row in the table.  I would probably use triggers to record the action that "triggered" the badge, if you will.  Then, a cron script could come award the badges.

In your case, it's a pretty simple query to tell if someone needs to be awarded a comments badge, so I would handle that directly from the CRON:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
LEFT JOIN users_badges ON users_badges.user_id = comments.user_id AND users_badges.description = 'First Comment'
WHERE users_badges.badge_id IS NULL
GROUP BY comments.user_id
```

Theoretically, you could insert a badge record for each of the returned results.  This was off the top of my head, but you get the idea.

For more complex queries, I would still probably insert into some sort of activity table to simplify things.  This also helps separate your implementation a bit--what do you do if the "description" for the badge changes in the future?  Normalization will help that kind of thing.

Comment: If the description of the badge changes, nothing happens. The badge has a `badge_id` field, which is referenced instead of the badge name. I'm not sure why you chose the badge name rather than the ID. Is there a reason? I'm not sure I understand the rest of your answer, either. The schema wouldn't need to change and even if it did, it wouldn't be drastic enough to break my queries. And if it was drastic, patching up a few queries would be the least of my worries considering the massive changes I'd have to make to the codebase. Am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: I think we're missing each other a bit.  Yes, using the ID would be better, but then you'd have to hardcode the ID, so I assumed the ID was some sort of autoincrement, and it was really the description you were concerned with.  The question to ask here is this: why would you store an SQL query in the table?  Is it really that hard to write the query in the cron script?

Comment: Since the badges are dynamic (i.e. editable via a page) and the conditions are complex, I can't see a solution other than this.